# SQL DB Creation during deployment

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have designed my SQL Server tables through Microsoft SQL Management Studio and wrote a c# application based on the database created.
While installing the application, I must create the database from a deployer.  Can Someone say about the easy way to get that done.

Comment: Look here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10032/Deploy-SQL-Server-databases-easily-with-an-Install

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used SQL managment studio. There is an option to generate scripts from the databases and tables. I generated the script and executed it by the programming lanugages as how i execute queries.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid there is no really easy way.

There is a tool called Roundhouse http://code.google.com/p/roundhouse/ which allows to deploy a database from script. You can integrate it in your setup but you'll have to care about server access rights yourself.

Or you can try some installer tools - wix, installshield etc, nearly all of them have tools to create a database.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11493/Create-database-during-installation-of-a-NET-appli